# Como criar uma keystore no prompt do windows?

Tags: android, prompt

Eu quero assinar o apk do meu aplicativo que já está pronto faz 1 mês, mas não consigo de nenhuma forma criar essa tal 'keystore'. Já tentei online, no Android Studio(zzz) e estou tentando no prompt de comando a 2 semanas. Já tentei seguir alguns tutoriais para isso mas pedem para instalar o java e depois um JDK e abrir o prompt como administrador e mesmo assim não funciona de nenhuma forma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço bastante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tens que adicionar o keyTool como variavel de ambiente!

Comment: Como que eu faço isso?

Comment: Mais precisamente, tem que adicionar o caminho onde está o aplicativo `keytool.exe` à variável de ambiente `PATH`. Ele fica na subpasta `bin` da pasta da JRE ou JDK (não lembro agora). Exemplos aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211919/errorkeytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-p

Comment: Não acredito que deu certo * o * Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Veja esse vídeo, nele tem um passo a passo para publicar um app https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rj1w9atPpHk